# AWS S3 trigger and MySQL LOAD DATA FROM S3 function

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

Is there a way to execute the LOAD DATA FROM S3 function everytime an object is created in an S3 bucket where the LOAD DATA FROM S3 function has a dynamic bucket/path and SET statements?  Something like this:

```
LOAD DATA FROM S3  's3://' + @bucket + '/' + @key
    INTO TABLE FisImportRows
    (RowData)
    SET
    FisImportRowsGUID = uuid(),
    FisImportGUID = @docId;
```

If so, how?  What are the options for this?

Thank you.

Comment: if you want this automated, you will have bucket and key, but where does `@docId` come from?

Comment: use an s3 trigger to send an sqs message and have a daemon reading the sqs queue and doing the load data.  or have it execute a lambda that does the load data.

Comment: Where @docId would be and sql variable not shown in this code example.  The problem is Load Data is limited in where/how it can be executed.  As per MySQL docs, we cannot use a file name as a parameter (https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=39115). and probably for similar reasons this statement fails using Typesripte and Prisma. I have an eventbridge event calling a lambda that tried callind Load Data with Prisma and it fails.

Comment: then it sounds like your question is really how to form and execute a raw sql statement in Prisma, instead of using parameters?  does this help: https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/raw-database-access

Comment: Thanks but no, that does not help. I already know how to do that, but you cannot execute the Load Data function from prisma, or in a stored procedure constructing the function with dynamic sql, etc.  its a great function but has a lot of limitations the Oracle has not bothered to address.  would be nice to execute this somehow from an S3 trigger

Comment: not sure what the limitation you refer to is, and the bug you link doesn't enlighten me.  you should be able to form a string that is the entire sql statement in your lambda client.  and you should be able to use Prisma to execute that sql statement.  what am I missing?